# In GPS Fetching nearest place comparing with my curren location in android

Tags: android, gps, locationmanager, locationlistener

In android i fetched the latitude and longitude of the current position, i also have other two co-ordinates, i need to compare the two co-ordinates with met which is my co-ordinates and get the nearest one dynamically. I tried it but dynamically how to get it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `distanceTo(Location dest)` for comparing locations or `distanceBetween(double startLatitude, double startLongitude, double endLatitude, double endLongitude, float[] results)` for comparing coordinates.

Both methods give you the distance between two points. If you do it dynamically you only have to calculete wich is smaller.

More info about them: [Location Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html)